# Nonlinear polynomial Diophantine equations

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

I am interested in whether there exist nontrivial (i.e., non-constant) solutions to any or all of the equations
\begin{align*}
P(x, x^{-1})^2 + Q(x, x^{-1})^2 + 1 &= 0, \\
P(x, x^{-1})^2 + Q(x, x^{-1})^4 + 1 &= 0, \\
P(x, x^{-1})^2 + Q(x, x^{-1})^3 + 1 &= 0, \\
P(x, x^{-1})^2 + Q(x, x^{-1})^3 + Q(x, x^{-1}) &= 0, \\
P(x, x^{-1})^2 + Q(x, x^{-1})^5 + 1 &= 0,
\end{align*}
where $P$ and $Q$ are single-variable Laurent polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.  For example, a straightforward solution to the first equation is
\begin{equation*}
P(x, x^{-1}) = \frac{x - x^{-1}}{2}, \quad Q(x, x^{-1}) = \frac{i(x + x^{-1})}{2}.
\end{equation*}
I would like to know whether the other equations have nontrivial solutions, and if so, whether there exists a method for generating solutions or for classifying all solutions.  Comments on the more general equation $P(x, x^{-1})^a + Q(x, x^{-1})^b + 1 = 0$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, would be appreciated as well.

Comment: So we are not looking for simultaneous solutions, but for every equation separately? For example, the last equation has a solution $Q(x,x^{-1})=0$ and $P(x,x^{-1})=i$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Right, I should have been more clear - I am looking for solutions to each equation separately. Also, I am interested in solutions where $P$ and $Q$ are not constant.

Comment: A version now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345519/diophantine-equation-in-laurent-polynomials